# Generalised method to clean data for text classification

Tags: python, regex, text-classification

Whilst searching for a text classification method, I came across this Python code which was used in the pre-processing step

```
REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean_text(text):
    """
        text: a string 
        return: modified initial string
    """
    text = text.lower() # lowercase text
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text) # replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text. substitute the matched string in REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE with space.
    text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub('', text) # remove symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text. substitute the matched string in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE with nothing. 
    text = text.replace('x', '')
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) # remove stopwords from text
    return text
```

**OP**

I then tested this section of code to understand the syntax and its purpose

```
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
text = '[0a;m]'
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub(' ', text)
# returns ' 0a m ' whilst I thought it would return '   ;  '
```

**Question:** why didn't the code replace `0`, `a`, and `m` although `0-9a-z` was specified inside the `[ ]`? Why did it replace `;` although that character wasn't specified?

**Edit to avoid being marked as duplication:**

My perceptions of the code are:

1. The line `BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')` is confusing. Including the characters `#`, `+`, and `_` inside the `[ ]`made me think the line trying to remove the characters in the list (because no word in an English dictionary would contain those *bad* characters `#+_`, I believe?). Consequently, it made me interpret the `^` as the start of a string (instead of negation). Thus, the original post (which was kindly answered by Tim Pietzcker and Raymond Hettinger). The two lines `REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE` and `BAD_SYMBOLS_RE` should had been combined into one such as

```
REMOVE_PUNCT = re.compile('[^0-9a-z]')
text = REMOVE_PUNCT.sub('', text)
```

2. I also think the code `text = text.replace('x', '')` (which was meant to remove the IDs that were masked as XXX-XXXX.... in the raw data) will lead to bad outcome, for example the word `next` will become `net`.

**Additional questions**:

1. Are my perceptions reasonable?
2. Should numbers/digits be removed from text?
3. Could you please recommend an overall/general strategy/code for text pre-processing for (English) text classification?

Comment: The `^` at the beginning of your character class means match any character **not** in this class

Answer (score 2):

Here's some documentation about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Basically, `[abc]` means "any one of `a`, `b`, or `c`" whereas `[^abc]` means "any character that is *not* `a`, `b`, or `c`".

So your regex operation removes every non-digit, non-letter character except space, `#`, `+` and `_` from the string, which explains the result you're getting.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim Pietzcker. I overlooked the meaning of `^`, thinking it referred to the start of a string! Could you please confirm the text.replace('x', '') would lead to unintended outcome before I accept your answer?

Comment: Yes, outside of a character class, `^` does mean "start of string". And your suspicion about what happens with `text.replace('x', '')` is correct.

Comment: Hi Tim. Sorry I had to reverse my acceptance as there were additional questions.

Answer (score 1):

**General rules**

The square brackets specify any one single character.

Roughly `[xyz]` is a short-cut for `(x|y|z)` but without creating a group.

Likewise `[a-z]` is a short-cut for `(a|b|c|...|y|z)`.

The interpretation of character sets can be a little tricky.  The start and end points get converted to their [ordinal positions](http://www.asciitable.com/) and the range of matching characters is inferred from there.  For example `[A-z]` converts *A* to 65 and *z* to 122, so everything from 65 to 122 is included.  That means that it also matches characters like *^* which convert to 94.  It also means that characters like *ö* won't match because that converts to 246 which is outside the range.

Another interesting form on character classes uses the *^* to invert the selection.  For example, `[^a-z]` means "any character not in the range from *a* to *z*.

The full details are in the "character sets" section of the [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re).

**Specific Problem**

In the OP's example, `BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')`, the caret *^* at the beginning inverts the range so that the listed symbols are **excluded** from the search.

That is why the code **didn't** replace *0*, *a*, and *m* although `0-9a-z` was specified inside the `[ ]`.  Essentially, it treated the specified characters as good characters.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I'm learning new information (about ordinal positions)! Thanks, Raymond. I *always* feel bewildered when interpreting a regular expression as it has so many rules of which some of them seem overlapping!

Comment: @Nemo You're not the only one :-)   Very few people know all of the symbols and all of the rules.